# Contenteditable Not working properly on firefox

Tags: firefox, contenteditable

Hi I'm working on a custom text editor, on a linux 64 machine (if it can help).
Since the javascript "document.execCommand" has been deprecated, I'm working with "selection" and "range" and other javascript objects and functions.
I'm using an external div (as textarea) with the attribute contenteditable = true.
Everything seems fine until the text editor generate, inside the main editable div, tags like: span, ol, li ...
In Firefox (Chrome, and Opera work fine) the editor let the user write inside the tag until he press enter to go to a new line.
At this point if the user try to get back (to correct something for example) these tags are not editable anymore.
I tried to give to those tags the same attribute contenteditable = true, but no luck;
The only way I can get back and edit them is by clicking with the mouse right button.
Any idea on how I can keep all the tags "contenteditable" inside the main div?
The file I'm working on is thousands of lines long so I simplified the problem in the snipped below.

```js
/**
  the text editor object
*/
function TextEditor( args ){
  this.editorId = args.editorId;
  this.container = document.querySelector('#' + this.editorId );
  var self = this;
  this.setOrderList = function(){
    document.execCommand('insertorderedlist');
  }
  this.initialize = function(){
    if( self.textArea.innerHTML === '' ){
      var div = document.createElement('div');
          self.textArea.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
  
  if ( this.container ) {
   this.textArea = this.container.querySelector('.text-area');
   this.orderedList = this.container.querySelector('#orederd-list');
   this.orderedList.addEventListener('click', this.setOrderList);
   this.textArea.addEventListener('focus', this.initialize);
  } 

}
var args = {
  editorId : 'container'
}
var editor = new TextEditor( args );
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="buttons-container">
    <ul id="buttons">
      <li id="orederd-list" class="button"><i class="fas fa-list-ol"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="text-area" contenteditable="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: execCommand isn't really deprecated yet (there is still no replacement for most of its uses). For instance, you still need it to set the kind of new line separator to use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#differences_in_markup_generation That being said, contentEditable is unfortunately broken everywhere, so I can't promise just setting this will fix your issue (btw a [live example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) would be nice)

Comment: I know so far execCommand works fine in all the browser I used, but I've been asked to replace it. Just because they don't want to wake up and find that their editor isn't working anymore because some browser actually decided to remove the functionality.

Comment: The strange thing is that the editor works just fine, even in Firefox, with tags like DIV, EM, STRONG, FONT, the user can go back and edit the content. no problem there.

Comment: What I said is that you can not replace all of execCommand just yet, so you'll have to explain to your client that you still need it for some features. Do replace the ones you can (e.g copy, selection etc.) with the new APIs, but to set the new line separator in a cross-browser way, you still need execCommand.

Comment: I just tried using "execCommand('insertorderedlist')", and I've go the same identical problem. It works with Chrome and Opera but not with Firefox. Same identical problem as above.

Comment: Why insertOL? The one I linked to is defaultParagraphSeparator

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found What's the problem is.
In the main style sheet I have the following instruction:

```
a, li, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p{
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
-khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently supported by Chrome and Opera */}
```

this instruction prevent users to select text from the website.
In Browsers like Chrome, Edge, Opera... this css instruction does not work inside "contenteditable" elements, while for some reason in Firefox it does.
For those interested, the I changed for the text editor main div the instruction:

```
-moz-user-select: none;
```

into:

```
-moz-user-select: text;
```

and now everything is fine.